# Ubuntu 18.04 - Network manager - "Supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up" after reboot!

Tags: networking, server, wireless, network-manager

I'm getting this error after a reboot when the connection has been working fine before reboot. It seems if I restart my router at the same time as the reboot It has no troube. I'm using NextCloud and the remote interface is still available on the public IP, but I can't connect to Cockpit on a local IP, nor can I SSH locally. Very weird.

It's corrected itself after about 30 minutes twice now, even though I didn't do anything! Can anyone give me any pointers as to what the problem might be? Here are my network errors: Many thanks!

```
09:16 <info> [1530864945.7008] device (wlp4s1): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
09:16 <info> [1530864945.7007] device (wlp4s1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
09:15 <error> [1530864945.7007] sup-iface[0x5625e3c33db0,wlp4s1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
09:15 <warn> [1530864945.5894] device (wlp4s1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
09:15 <info> [1530864935.7040] device (wlp4s1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
09:15 <error> [1530864935.7040] sup-iface[0x5625e3c33db0,wlp4s1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
09:15 <warn> [1530864935.5880] device (wlp4s1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
09:15 <info> [1530864925.7089] device (wlp4s1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
09:15 <error> [1530864925.7088] sup-iface[0x5625e3c33d00,wlp4s1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
09:15 <warn> [1530864925.5937] device (wlp4s1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
```

`ifconfig` :

```
wlp4s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether 00:1f:1f:dd:d6:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packet 763  bytes 86695 (86.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 663  bytes 502543 (502.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropeed 0  overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: did you check `ifconfig` (`ip a` if `ifconfig` not install) or `dmesg` ? Some good information are prompt by these 2 commands

Comment: I have had a look, this is what comes from ifconfig, it looks fine? https://i.imgur.com/i5q0FZK.png

Comment: no problem from ifconfig, that will help others members ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I've figured out installing Cockpit is the culrprit as it installs NetworkManager as a dependancy and that conflicts with networkd.